# Macbook pro 15 late 2015: Black screen after login

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac

I got a macbook pro (15-inch late 2015 model https://support.apple.com/kb/sp719?locale=en_US) that has problems starting up. Before, it got stuck at a black screen with a white Apple logo screen with the loading bar, and it keeps repeating that. I then could enter the safe mode but the laptop is really slow and could not open any files, so I erased all data and reinstalled the OS. The laptop then has only a black screen. I can still hear the fan running, but nothing appears, just a black screen. I then try entering into Safe mode and can continue setting up the new OS.

After setting up everything, I restarted the computer (because it was in Safe Mode), and everything works fine up to the Login interface. After I entered my password and log in, there is only a black screen.
I already tried resetting NVRAM, SMC, Disk Utility in Recovery Mode, Check the file system, reinstalling OS as mentioned above as suggested by this article (https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/wont-turn-on-boot-3423817/) , and None of them works.

Does anyone know what is wrong with the laptop? and how can I reset absolutely everything? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you boot in Verbose Mode (hold CMD+V during boot), record a high-speed / slow-motion video (using an iPhone or something similar) of the console text during boot, and attach the still frame grabs to your question so that we can see where the hang occurs?

Comment: I tried but it is very blurry and cannot see any text. I own a very old fone (samsung s8)